# Get max for more than one object property

Tags: javascript

I have code that finds the max of two properties, but I don't know that it's the best way to do this. I am inside jQuery's `$.getJSON(URI, function(json){})` call.

The goal is to make a bar chart with 2 bars that's exactly the width of the longest bar.

Currently to find the maximum value:

```js
var max = Math.max.apply(this, $.map(json, function(d){
    return Math.max(d.bar1, d.bar2);
}));
```

Is there a better way?

Edit: A json string, as requested:

```
[
    {
        "bar1": "15",
        "bar2": "13"
    },
    {
        "bar1": "20",
        "bar2": "25"
    },
    {
        "bar1": "10",
        "bar2": "18"
    }
]
```

`max` should be equal to 25 with this as an input.

Comment: Your problem does not have anything to do with JSON. Once it is parsed you are working with JavaScript objects.

Answer (score 3):

This works, and is marginally shorter, albeit not necessarily more efficient:

```
var max = json.reduce(function(p, d) {  // p is the current max
    return Math.max(p, d.bar1, d.bar2);
}, 0);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/PF8Me/1/

Note that it does assume that all of your values are positive (hence the "initial value" of zero supplied to `reduce`).

Use a shim for [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) if you're not using an ES5 browser.

Comment: @Caleb and for not needing jQuery ;-)

Comment: Curious, why don't people like jQuery? I've seen that sentiment all over stack overflow.

Comment: @Caleb actually I use jQuery all the time.  I was mostly referring to using standard ES5 functions (e.g. `reduce`, `map`) instead of `$.map`.